# Google App Engine service-to-service authentication (non-programmatic)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a scenario where I have an on-premise GUI application which has a "Web Service Invoke" component which I use to call a GAE API.
In the GUI application, it is possible to:

- store credentials
- create a chain of web services/http(s) calls that can integrate an output of preceding https(s) call as a query parameter or header value into the next http(s) call
- retrieve a value from JSON response of the http(s) call

But it is not possible to programmatically do anything. The Web Service widget has fields for passing API URL, query parameters and headers only.

I'm looking to do a service-to-service authentication for the API call and the API should be protected using IAP as well.

I'm aware of the recommended approach is to create a service account and provide the service account JSON key file to the client and the client signs a JWT token and pass it as a bearer token. But as I only have widgets, no programming possible, therefore signing JWT token is not an option.

I was looking at Google OAuth or IAM APIs which can support "client_credentials" grant type wherein I can get an access token using just clientId and clientSecret - something possible in Apigee. But it seems this grant type is not supported by Google OAuth APIs.

I also looked at Cloud Endpoints using API KEY - so the current thought is to the client passes API KEY in header/parameter for authentication to Cloud Endpoints, then Cloud Endpoints uses its service account to get access through IAP, and finally, I'm thinking that the client can also send in "Basic Auth" credentials through Authorization header which the GAE API backend service validates. The additional "Basic Auth" is because Google recommends using another auth method in addition to API KEY.

I would like a simpler solution if possible using GAE and IAP only. Any other suggestions, especially using time-limited tokens, that can work over only http(s) calls (non-programmatic or client library), is much appreciated.
Any alternatives or things to try is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this server-to-server authentication using JWT [Google API Authentication](https://github.com/tintu2391/gsuite-oauth2-connector)